# Linux-Ubuntu: Shared Memory with a variable dynamically allocated that must be change by other executables

Tags: linux, dynamic, fork, shared-memory, allocation

I'm trying to just add to an int dynamically allocated in the (START) executable.
This variable must be shared using shared memory with other executables (SECOND).
For some reason when i try to operate into this variable with the (SECOND) executable the software just SKIP it and continue with (START) executable.
I'm still new to this topic...

[This is the (START) executable code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o88Qv.png)

[The header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGuHD.png)

[The (SECOND) executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5AMO.png)

[The Makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX9JH.png)

by the way all this files are in the same folder
Sorry for my bad english i hope someone can help me.
Also this code work if i use variables NOT dynamically allocated

> START

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(){
key_t shmKEY;
shmKEY= ftok(".",'a');

int shmID = shmget(shmKEY,4*sizeof(INT),IPC_CREAT | 0664);
INT A;

A=shmat(shmID,NULL,0);
//A=malloc(4*sizeof(INT));

A[0]=1;
A[1]=2;
A[2]=3;
A[3]=4;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("[%d]",A[i]);
}
printf("\n");

pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid<0){
    perror("ERRORE FORK\n");
}
else if(pid==0){
    execl("./SECOND","./SECOND",NULL);
    exit(1);
}

if(pid>0){
    wait(NULL);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("[%d]",A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}



//free(A);
shmctl(shmID,IPC_RMID,0);
return 0;
```

}

> SECOND

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main(){
key_t shmKEY;
shmKEY= ftok(".",'a');

int shmID = shmget(shmKEY,0,IPC_CREAT | 0664);
INT A;

A=shmat(shmID,NULL,0);
printf("DEBUG0\n");
A[0]=A[0]+1;
A[1]=A[1]+1;
A[2]=A[2]+1;
A[3]=A[3]+1;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("[%d]",A[i]);
    }
printf("\n");
printf("DEBUG1\n"); 
return 0;
```

}

> HEADER

```
#ifndef _TEST_H
#define _TEST_H
typedef int* INT;

#endif
```

> MAKEFILE

```
All: START SECOND

START:main.o
     gcc main.o -o START

SECOND:second.o
     gcc second.o -o SECOND

second.o:second.c test.h
     gcc -c second.c        

main.o: main.c test.h
     gcc -c main.c

clean:
     rm *.o START SECOND
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `A=malloc(4*sizeof(INT));` replaces the pointer to the shared memory with a pointer to the local heap memory.

Comment: Get rid of the call to `malloc()`.

Comment: i removed the A=malloc(..) i'll rmeove the immages and pu the code, i didn't understand what you mean with "replace the pointer to the shared memory with one to the heap memory"

Comment: `malloc()` allocates new memory from the heap. You assigned that to `A`. So now `A` contains a pointer to that heap memory, instead of the pointer to the shared memory that you assigned on the previous line with `shmat()`.

Comment: i'm really sorry to bother again, but i don't get what i'm missing, should i do something else other than removing malloc?
It still doesn't make me add values to "A" with the executable SECOND
also it doesn't make me copy form VM linux to windows so i should later login with the VM and copy and paste the code

Comment: You're not using the same shared memory in the parent and child. The parent uses token `a`, the child uses token `b`.

Comment: Are you ever going to post the code here?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, in just had to remove malloc and not be blind , i must study better this topic.

Comment: the answer is better suited as a comment.